# MySQL Insert results of select

Tags: mysql

I have a many to many relationship and am trying to insert a new relationship.  At the point I'm doing the insert I don't know the id so would need to look it up.  My table structure looks something like this:

```
**person**
id
name

**film**
id
title

**person_film**
personId
filmId
```

Given a person's id and a list of film titles (but not their ids) I'm only able to insert these relationships into the person_film table in two steps.

```
SELECT id FROM film WHERE title="film1" OR title="film2";
```

Then the results of that can be used in an insert:

```
INSERT INTO person_film (personId, filmId) VALUES (5, 5),(5, 7);
```

Is there a way of doing this in a single SQL statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with a subquery:

```
INSERT INTO person_film (personId, filmId)
  SELECT 5, id FROM film
    WHERE title IN("film1","film2");
```

Here the `5` is the `personId` value and the `filmId` will be retrieved from the `film` table.

Answer (score 0):

Use numeric literals with aliases inside a SELECT statement. No () are necessary around the SELECT component.

```
INSERT INTO person_film (personId, filmId)
  SELECT
    /* Literal number values with column aliases */
    1 AS fpersonId,
    2 AS filmId,

  FROM film 
  WHERE title="film1" OR title="film2";
```

Note that in context of an INSERT INTO...SELECT, the aliases are not actually necessary and you can just SELECT 1, 2 but in a normal SELECT you'll need the aliases to access the columns returned.